# Hide and Unhide EditText

Tags: android

I am trying to hide or show edit text on selecting items from spinner in my app.Here is the code please suggest how to fix it

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.country_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
         rlDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         rlTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

     }
 });
```

Comment: What you exactly want to do??And what the output you get with above code???

Answer (score 2):

```
rlDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

will make the View 'disappear'.

Comment: Based on the item selected call the above method to hide or show the edit box

Answer (score 1):

Hope your spinner and its click event worls fine..Then you can add below code to disable or ebable the edittext:

```
     int count = 0;
         spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            **if(count == 0){
               rlDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              count == 1;
            }else{
              rlDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              count = 0;
        }**
   }
    });
```

It will set edittext visibility everytime you click on spinner.Hope this works..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have achieved what I think you were trying:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (Objects.equals(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(), "<item_text_value>")) {

                rlDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rlTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            rlDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rlTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

Hope this help you -in case you are still having this issue -or anyone else currently having it.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

below code for hode Edittext

```
EditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EditText ta=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.***);
ta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```