# Can i let the user delete/close an edit text if he doesn't want to type anything?

Tags: android, android-edittext, user-input

i have a lot of EditTexts. I want the user to delete some edittexts if he doesn't want to type anything and i want that edittext to go away from the screen. Can i do that?

Comment: How about `setVisibility(View.GONE)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and Unhide EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012548/hide-and-unhide-edittext)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll likely want to submit future questions with more care and context, to help readers understand what you're asking. For example,  add Android in your title; check your basic English usage -- even non-native speakers know to capitalize "I"; ask yourself if you would understand what you've asked, and generally try to make it as easy as possible to help you.

Comment: edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by changing the visibility. First set visibility of the edittext as setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) then setVisibility(View.GONE).